# Printf-debugging in gnuplot

Tags: debugging, gnuplot

For debugging a little gnuplot script, I would like to insert a *printf* inside a user-defined function, so that I can trace what values it receives and returns.

Is there a way to do that?

For instance, this function returns a NaN in some cases (e.g., when n=100):

```
eps_rf_i(n, i) = binom(n,i) * eps**i * (1-eps)**(n-i)
eps_rf(n) = sum[i=n/2 : n] eps_rf_i(n,i)
```

I tried to insert a printf in the function *eps_rf_i* like this:

```
eps_rf_i(n, i) = ( print binom(n,i) * eps**i * (1-eps)**(n-i),  binom(n,i) * eps**i * (1-eps)**(n-i) )
eps_rf(n) = sum[i=n/2 : n] eps_rf_i(n,i)
```

but gnuplot reports an error right after the *print* :

```
gnuplot> eps_rf_i(n, i) = ( print binom(n,i) * eps**i * (1-eps)**(n-i),  binom(n,i) * eps**i * (1-eps)**(n-i) )
                                  ^
"error_rate.plt", line 11: ')' expected
```

Is there any other way to debug *eps_rf* ?

All hints and insights will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot test your script which is not working because some functions are not defined.

You cannot use print command in the user defined function.
But you can append the value you want to print.

```
value=""
eps_rf_i(n, i) = (value=value.sprintf("%f\n",binom(n,i) * eps**i * (1-eps)**(n-i)),  binom(n,i) * eps**i * (1-eps)**(n-i) )
eps_rf(n) = sum[i=n/2 : n] eps_rf_i(n,i)
```

result->

```
print eps_rf(10)
```

You can check the traced value

```
print value
```

Thanks,